# how to get data outside javascript function

Tags: javascript

im wondering if i can get some help here, im not a skilled coder by far, but im trying to retrieve results outside the function and the result in log  im getting is **Undefined**

```
var pricecrex;

getDataFromAPI("https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_WAGE]", 
    true, 
    function(data){
        var resultcrex = JSON.parse(data);
        if (resultcrex !== "undefined") {
            if (resultcrex) {
                var pricecrex = resultcrex.Tickers[0].Last
            }
            else {
                msg.reply("0")
            }
        }
    }
);

console.log(pricecrex);
```

Comment: `getDataFromAPI` fetches the data asynchronously, so you are logging `pricecrex` before it is assigned its actual value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because Ajax requests are async. `console.log()` gets executed before response is received from request, and thus before setting value in `pricecrex`. So you were getting `undefined`.

```
var pricecrex;

getDataFromAPI("https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_WAGE]", 
true, function(data) {
        var resultcrex = JSON.parse(data);
        if (resultcrex !== "undefined") {
            if (resultcrex) {
                pricecrex = resultcrex.Tickers[0].Last;
                print(pricecrex);
            }
            else {
                msg.reply("0")
            }
        }
    }
);

function print(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: and there is no good reason to declare `var pricecrex;` twice. The second one should be a simple assignment

Comment: What if I not just want to log the data? What if I call the getDataFromAPI to get the data returned? Wouldn't I have to call the print function then to be able to get the data returned?

Answer (score 1):

The nature of Javascript is continue running code once an asynchronous function has been started. So you run `getDataFromAPI()`, and then while that's running, the interpreter goes to the next piece of code, which is your `console.log(pricecrex)`.

So you can either run the `console.log(pricecrex)` directly in the callback, `function(data){}`, or to keep things cleaner, wrap your `console.log()` within a function and call that function from within your callback.

Example:

```
let someVar;

someAsync('someurl.com', (data) =>{
    someVar = data;
    callTheConsole()
})

function callTheConsole(){
     console.log(someVar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the value to the variable. Pass it to another function. Thus the value passed to another function is not 'undefined'.

```
function validation(pricecrex){
    console.log(pricecrex);
}
```

```
getDataFromAPI("https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_WAGE]", 
    true, 
    function(data){
        var resultcrex = JSON.parse(data);
        if (resultcrex !== "undefined") {
            if (resultcrex) {
                var pricecrex = resultcrex.Tickers[0].Last;
                validation(pricecrex);
            }
            else {
                msg.reply("0")
            }
        }
    }
);
```

For more information, check out the below link. Detailed information with examples is available.
[How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1)?